# Issues with RxSwift and AVKit

Tags: swift, macos, video, rx-swift, avkit

I am building what I hope to be a simple macOS application that will locally stored videos selected from a popUP button.

The application is two windows 1) the AVPlayerView and 2) a simple control panel that allows the user to select and play the flagged videos on the other window.

All of this works very well in XCode. When the saved URL is selected, it is made into an AVAsset which is it turn made into an AVPlayerItem. The next process I have tried successfully(in Xcode) two ways: create a 1) PublishSubect or a 2) PublishSubject. In the view controller for the AVPlayerview window, I subscribe to the control panel's publish subject and either update the AVplayerView's player with the AVPlayerItem

```
 destinationVC.videoSubject.subscribe(
                onNext: { [weak self] item in
                   self?.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
                }
            ).disposed(by: bag)
```

or I inject the player in a similar fashion. Either of these options works flawlessly when I run the application in XCode. The issue that I have is when I archive it to run the app on my computer, when I select the video to be played, the app crashes.

I isolated this task to a background thread with the hopes of better sniffing out an error but the resulting crash report does not make much sense to me:

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: Background
0   [myinfo].STSVideoPlayer 0x000000010e655476 closure #1 in closure #1 in VideoViewController.prepare(for:sender:) + 134 (VideoViewController.swift:40)
1   [myinfo].STSVideoPlayer 0x000000010e655499 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 25
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e6d56c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e6d6658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e6dbc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e6dc5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6e6e5c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6e930a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6e92fb77 start_wqthread + 15
```

I am, obviously, over my head here. Any insight that you may have would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more detailed crash report, and it turns out that I was force-unwrapping some nils. I am not sure how that got through in XCode, but now everything is working swimmingly.